# 10002 Security header is not valid error when calling DoCapture in live mode

Tags: paypal

I need some helps regarding to Paypal express checkout. Here is my case
- I can do: SetExpressCheckout, DoExpressCheckout successfully
- But I was unable to DoCapture to capture authorized amount. And here is the error "10002 Security header is not valid". Noted that this only happen on live mode, it worked fine in sandbox mode.

Please help. thanks Thanh

Comment: should be because the API credentials are missed up with sandbox or API credentials are incorrect

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have searched around this before posting the question. It can do SetExpressCheckout, DoExpressCheckout ok without problem, but not when DoCapture. Any other idea?

Comment: can you give me the express checkout token with paypal email address?

Comment: Can I give you transaction ID? if yes, here is one 7X304177H9196134E. thanks for your support

Comment: everything looks good here . Doexpresscehckout is completed successfully. can you try again? may be if you can share your code?

Comment: According to my posted question, we are ok with SetExpressCheckout, DoExpressCheckout without any problem. But we have this error when DoCapture

Answer (score 0):

After doing **DoExpressCheckoutPayment** get the authorizationID and use it in DoCapture

```
Endpoint URL: https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp
HTTP method: POST
POST data:
USER=merchant_user_name
&PWD=merchant_password
&SIGNATURE=merchant_signature
&METHOD=DoExpressCheckoutPayment
&VERSION=95
&TOKEN=EC-470284976K7901234    #Token from the SetExpressCheckout response
&PAYERID=3TXTXECKFU1234    #Customer account ID, from the GetExpressCheckoutDetails response
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Authorization    #Enables you to collect payment in the future
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=1
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=USD
```

Response

```
--------
TOKEN=EC%2d470284976K7901234
&ACK=Success
&VERSION=95
&PAYMENTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONID=20K92515TX2901234    #Use this value as the authorization ID in a DoCapture request
&PAYMENTINFO_0_SECUREMERCHANTACCOUNTID=QJSRDC4JW1234
&PAYMENTINFO_0_ACK=Success
```

...

**DoCapture** call

### Request

```
Endpoint URL: https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp
HTTP method: POST
POST data:
USER=merchant_user_name
&PWD=merchant_password
&SIGNATURE=merchant_signature
&METHOD=DoCapture
&VERSION=95
&AUTHORIZATIONID=20K92515TX2901234    #Authorization ID. Specify the value of PAYMENTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONID from the DoExpressCheckoutPayment response)
&AMT=1    #The amount of the payment
&CURRENCYCODE=USD
&COMPLETETYPE=Complete    #Indicates that for the authorization specified, this is the last payment capture
```

### Response

```
AUTHORIZATIONID=20K92515TX2901234
&ACK=Success
&TRANSACTIONID=2KF46316MJ7751234    #New transaction ID for this payment
&PARENTTRANSACTIONID=20K92515TX2901234    #Same as the ID of the original authorization
&TRANSACTIONTYPE=expresscheckout
&PAYMENTTYPE=instant
&AMT=1%2e00
&FEEAMT=0%2e33
&TAXAMT=0%2e00
&CURRENCYCODE=USD
&PAYMENTSTATUS=Completed
...
```

**Reference** : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-singleAuthPayment-curl-etc/